# Como poner comas en un input tipo numerico

Tags: javascript, html

Hola como puedo poner comas a una columna tipo Decimal ya sea al principio en el input o despues con una convercion me la ponga automaticamente

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes formatear con la siguiente funcion:

```js
function formatear(dato) {
  return dato.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
 return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
    });
}

function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');
  var resultado3 = document.getElementById('resultado3');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2/100;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16/100;
  var t = iva - descuento;
        
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = 'Prima: ' + formatear(descuento.toFixed(2));
  total.innerHTML = 'Total: ' + formatear(iva.toFixed(2));
  resultado3.innerHTML = 'iva: ' + formatear(t.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<input id="valor" />
<input id="valor2" />
<button onClick="calcular();">Calcular</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="resultado3"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias..!!!

Comment: Y se puede que en un input tipo numerico agregar comas ( , ) o despues al jalarlo que se agregen?